# Passing exception to a method and throw this type of exception

Tags: c#, exception

How can I pass exception to a method and throw that type of exception in this method>

Here is my tryout:

```
    public static void AgainstNull<T, D>(T value, string paramName, D exception, string message)
        where T : class
        where D : Exception
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new exception(paramName, message);
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
        User user = await this.userManager.FindByNameAsync(assignRoleModel.Username);
        Guard.AgainstNull(user, nameof(user), ArgumentNullException, ErrorMessages.FindUserByNameError);
```

Comment: It seems you provide the exception only for the generic argument. So instead of having a *method-parameter* of type `D`, why not specifiying `D`via the generic argument: `Guard.AgainstNull<ArgumentNullException>(user, nameof(user), ErrorMessages.FindUser)`?

Comment: Why do you have aparemeter that you´re not using at all?

Comment: Why would you pass the exception to the method? From my point of view, creating this type of code, the thrown exception should be clear by naming convention. If I was to use this code, I dont really care about defining my own exception, but I would expect it to throw `ArgumentNullException` as the method name is AgainstNull.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen The idea is to have many custom types of exceptions that will return results to the users (BadRequestException, ForbiddenException and etc.)